# Insert the conditional select statement to a temp table using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_METR_MAN_FREQ_WISE_MBO_DETAILS 
    @BusLeadNm varchar(50),
    @FreqDesc  varchar(50),
    @Month varchar(50),
    @Quarter varchar(50)          
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if object_id('dbo.temp') is not null drop table dbo.temp

if @FreqDesc='Monthly'
begin
    select distinct m.MBO_Name,f.Freq_Desc,ml.[Weight]/100 as WeightFin,r.End_DT as Due_DT,l.Leader_ID
    ,g.Goal,g.goal_ytd
    ,g.goal_dt,g.goal_ytd_dt,r.end_dt
    from
    MBO m, LKUP_Frequency f,MBO_Leader ml,Leader_NM l,Result r
    ,mbo_goal g 
    where
    (l.Leader_Last+','+' '+l.Leader_First)=@BusLeadNm
    and ml.Leader_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    and r.MBO_ID=m.MBO_ID 
    and m.MBO_ID=ml.MBO_ID 
    and f.freq_id=(select Freq_ID from lkup_frequency where freq_desc=@FreqDesc)
    and m.Frequency_ID= f.freq_id
    and r.Result is null 
    and r.Result_DT is null 
    and m.Owner_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    --and month(r.End_DT)<=month(getdate()) and month(r.End_DT)>=month(convert(datetime,'2014-02-25')) 
    and m.mbo_id=g.mbo_id 
    and month(g.End_DT)=month(r.end_dt)
    and DATENAME(month,DATEADD(m,-1,r.End_DT)) = @Month
end

else if @FreqDesc='Quarterly'
begin

    if @Quarter='Q1'
    begin

    select distinct m.MBO_Name,f.Freq_Desc,ml.[Weight]/100 as WeightFin,r.End_DT as Due_DT,l.Leader_ID
        ,g.Goal,g.goal_ytd
    ,g.goal_dt,g.goal_ytd_dt,r.end_dt
    from
    MBO m, LKUP_Frequency f,MBO_Leader ml,Leader_NM l,Result r
    ,mbo_goal g 
    where
    (l.Leader_Last+','+' '+l.Leader_First)=@BusLeadNm
    and ml.Leader_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    and r.MBO_ID=m.MBO_ID 
    and m.MBO_ID=ml.MBO_ID 
    and f.freq_id=(select Freq_ID from lkup_frequency where freq_desc=@FreqDesc)
    and m.Frequency_ID= f.freq_id
    and r.Result is null 
    and r.Result_DT is null 
    and m.Owner_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    --and month(r.End_DT)<=month(getdate()) and month(r.End_DT)>=month(convert(datetime,'2014-02-25')) 
    and m.mbo_id=g.mbo_id 
    and month(g.End_DT)=month(r.end_dt)
    and DATENAME(month,DATEADD(m,-1,r.End_DT)) = 'March'
    end


    else if @Quarter='Q2'
    begin

    select distinct m.MBO_Name,f.Freq_Desc,ml.[Weight]/100 as WeightFin,r.End_DT as Due_DT,l.Leader_ID
        ,g.Goal,g.goal_ytd
    ,g.goal_dt,g.goal_ytd_dt,r.end_dt
    from
    MBO m, LKUP_Frequency f,MBO_Leader ml,Leader_NM l,Result r
    ,mbo_goal g 
    where
    (l.Leader_Last+','+' '+l.Leader_First)=@BusLeadNm
    and ml.Leader_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    and r.MBO_ID=m.MBO_ID 
    and m.MBO_ID=ml.MBO_ID 
    and f.freq_id=(select Freq_ID from lkup_frequency where freq_desc=@FreqDesc)
    and m.Frequency_ID= f.freq_id
    and r.Result is null 
    and r.Result_DT is null 
    and m.Owner_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    --and month(r.End_DT)<=month(getdate()) and month(r.End_DT)>=month(convert(datetime,'2014-02-25')) 
    and m.mbo_id=g.mbo_id 
    and month(g.End_DT)=month(r.end_dt)
    and DATENAME(month,DATEADD(m,-1,r.End_DT)) = 'June'
    end

    else if @Quarter='Q3'
    begin

    select distinct m.MBO_Name,f.Freq_Desc,ml.[Weight]/100 as WeightFin,r.End_DT as Due_DT,l.Leader_ID
        ,g.Goal,g.goal_ytd
    ,g.goal_dt,g.goal_ytd_dt,r.end_dt
    from
    MBO m, LKUP_Frequency f,MBO_Leader ml,Leader_NM l,Result r
    ,mbo_goal g 
    where
    (l.Leader_Last+','+' '+l.Leader_First)=@BusLeadNm
    and ml.Leader_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    and r.MBO_ID=m.MBO_ID 
    and m.MBO_ID=ml.MBO_ID 
    and f.freq_id=(select Freq_ID from lkup_frequency where freq_desc=@FreqDesc)
    and m.Frequency_ID= f.freq_id
    and r.Result is null 
    and r.Result_DT is null 
    and m.Owner_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    --and month(r.End_DT)<=month(getdate()) and month(r.End_DT)>=month(convert(datetime,'2014-02-25')) 
    and m.mbo_id=g.mbo_id 
    and month(g.End_DT)=month(r.end_dt)
    and DATENAME(month,DATEADD(m,-1,r.End_DT)) = 'September'
    end

    else if @Quarter='Q4'
    begin

    select distinct m.MBO_Name,f.Freq_Desc,ml.[Weight]/100 as WeightFin,r.End_DT as Due_DT,l.Leader_ID
        ,g.Goal,g.goal_ytd
    ,g.goal_dt,g.goal_ytd_dt,r.end_dt
    from
    MBO m, LKUP_Frequency f,MBO_Leader ml,Leader_NM l,Result r
    ,mbo_goal g 
    where
    (l.Leader_Last+','+' '+l.Leader_First)=@BusLeadNm
    and ml.Leader_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    and r.MBO_ID=m.MBO_ID 
    and m.MBO_ID=ml.MBO_ID 
    and f.freq_id=(select Freq_ID from lkup_frequency where freq_desc=@FreqDesc)
    and m.Frequency_ID= f.freq_id
    and r.Result is null 
    and r.Result_DT is null 
    and m.Owner_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    --and month(r.End_DT)<=month(getdate()) and month(r.End_DT)>=month(convert(datetime,'2014-02-25')) 
    and m.mbo_id=g.mbo_id 
    and month(g.End_DT)=month(r.end_dt)
    and DATENAME(month,DATEADD(m,-1,r.End_DT)) = 'December'
    end
end 

else if @FreqDesc='Annually'
begin
    select distinct m.MBO_Name,f.Freq_Desc,ml.[Weight]/100 as WeightFin,r.End_DT as Due_DT,l.Leader_ID
    ,g.Goal,g.goal_ytd
    ,g.goal_dt,g.goal_ytd_dt,r.end_dt
    from
    MBO m, LKUP_Frequency f,MBO_Leader ml,Leader_NM l,Result r
    ,mbo_goal g 
    where
    (l.Leader_Last+','+' '+l.Leader_First)=@BusLeadNm
    and ml.Leader_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    and r.MBO_ID=m.MBO_ID 
    and m.MBO_ID=ml.MBO_ID 
    and f.freq_id=(select Freq_ID from lkup_frequency where freq_desc=@FreqDesc)
    and m.Frequency_ID= f.freq_id
    and r.Result is null 
    and r.Result_DT is null 
    and m.Owner_ID=l.Leader_ID 
    --and month(r.End_DT)<=month(getdate()) and month(r.End_DT)>=month(convert(datetime,'2014-02-25')) 
    and m.mbo_id=g.mbo_id 
    and month(g.End_DT)=month(r.end_dt)
    and DATENAME(month,DATEADD(m,-1,r.End_DT)) = month(getdate())
end
```

Comment: I want to insert the above returned query with if conditions to a temp table??

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain what you actually want? with sample data and table definitions.

Comment: I want that starting from the If condition specified above the procedure returns some records, so how would I insert these records into the Temp table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create the temp table with same fields with your select query, here's how:

```
DECLARE @temptable TABLE (
    mbo_name VARCHAR(200),
    freq_desc INT,
    weightfin INT,
    ...
)
```

Then use the select statement after INSERT INTO temptable:

```
INSERT INTO @temptable
SELECT distinct m.MBO_Name,f.Freq_Desc,ml.[Weight]/100 as WeightFin,r.End_DT as   
       Due_DT,l.Leader_ID, g.Goal,g.goal_ytd, g.goal_dt, g.goal_ytd_dt, r.end_dt
FROM
...;

DROP @temptable;
```

OR you can use a simpler method, SELECT INTO:

```
SELECT distinct m.MBO_Name,f.Freq_Desc,ml.[Weight]/100 as WeightFin,r.End_DT as   
       Due_DT,l.Leader_ID, g.Goal,g.goal_ytd, g.goal_dt, g.goal_ytd_dt, r.end_dt,
       ...
INTO #temptable
FROM
...;

DROP #temptable;
```

Notice the `@` and `#`, `@` creates a table, while `#` creates a temporary one.

Comment: But above in my code I have starting with If condition. So how I would put that whole part in From part when I have to insert into temp table as you stated above?

Comment: The only difference between the query I suggested and yours is that I added `INTO #temptable`. That part inserts your select results into a temp table. If you're able to run the select inside the if statement, you should also be able to put it into a temp table just like my query.